# retrieving firebase data into a textview with no button in android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a few textviews which i want to change from firebase database on a daily basis
for that i am retrieving data from firebase realtime database to a textview i have tried many times but it just doesnt seem to work,please help me guys.

this is my java code.

```
       tv1 = findViewById ( R.id.tv1 );
       tv2 = findViewById ( R.id.tv2 );
       tv3 = findViewById ( R.id.tv3 );
       tv4 = findViewById ( R.id.tv4 );
       tv5 = findViewById ( R.id.tv5 );
       tv6 = findViewById ( R.id.tv6 );
       tv7 = findViewById ( R.id.tv7 );
       tv8 = findViewById ( R.id.tv8 );
       tv9 = findViewById ( R.id.tv9 );
       tv10 = findViewById ( R.id.tv10 );

       mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance ();
       ref= mDatabase.getReference ().child ("textview1");

       ref.addValueEventListener ( new ValueEventListener ( ) {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {


               String tv1s = snapshot.child ( "textview1" ).getValue ( String.class );
               String tv2s = snapshot.child ( "textview2" ).getValue ( String.class );
               String tv3s = snapshot.child ( "textview3" ).getValue ( String.class );
               String tv4s = snapshot.child ( "textview4" ).getValue ( String.class );
             

               tv1.setText ( tv1s );
               tv2.setText ( tv2s );
               tv3.setText ( tv3s );
               tv4.setText ( tv4s );
             



           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

           }
       } );
```

````
this is my firebase database 

``` {
  "textview1" : 2200,
  "textview10" : 244,
  "textview2" : 13,
  "textview3" : 12,
  "textview4" : 13,
 
} ```

when i open app all the text just vanishes and i dont any reason for that. i have lots of textview which i want to update from day to day basis if you guys have any suggestions i am open to hear it.

basic idea is to update values 
suppose i have 10 textview in gridlayout so they will be 10-1, 11-2, 12-3 and so on and here both or every numbers are textview i want to change this numbers everyday according to need so thas why i am asking for help. 

i am adding more words so that my question will be accepted and i think you all got the idea of what i am trying to say. i just want to change text or numbers in my case of my textviewe from firebase using firebase realtime database so that i can update those values regularly.
````

Comment: `i have tried many times but it just doesnt seem to work` welcome to the world of debugging, have you tried using breakpoints and logs to see what's happening and what isn't happening ? you have nothing happening inside `onCancelled`, are you sure that isn't being called ? do you know if your code ever goes inside `onDataChange` ? what does it return ? there's still plenty more you can do

Comment: @a_local_nobody can you please tell me what should i put inside oncancelled.i have copied this code from youtube video and there was nothing.sorry i dont have enough knowledge about it

Comment: well, the point i'm trying to make is that you should make use of logs and breakpoints to see what's happening in your code, so put a log statement in there, see if it shows up, you can even make use of a toast if you want, it's not going to make a difference to your app but at least you'll know what's actually happening, instead of guessing

Comment: First of all, as already a_local_nobody mentioned in his comment, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, error.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?